# Условия, реакция на событие, возможно ли такое?

Tags: css3, события

Доброго времени суток.

Появился такой вопрос о css3.
Есть 3 поля, определяю их по типу:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
```

Также есть поле - `[type="submit"]`.

Так вот нужно сделать, чтобы когда все 3 поля `required:valid`, то вот это поле `[type="submit"]` можно было оформить по своему вкусу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот [код](http://jsbin.com/nirehakaxe/1/edit?html,css,output) будет работать при условии, что все инпуты являются siblings.

```
[type="text"]:valid ~ [type="password"]:valid ~ [type="email"]:valid ~ [type="submit"] {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Не пойму, у тебя все работает, но у меня нет!
Может, из-за того, что у меня уже стили применены ко всем этим input?

Comment: Перетестировал, перепробовал, оказывается, нужно "раздеть" все мои поля от div'ов и прочих убрать у них стили, и только тогда все получится! (
Обидно, пробовал указать по div'но: `.cont form input[type="text"]:valid`  
Но тот же результат! (

Comment: Как можно сделать, если наши "братья и сестры" input'ы живут каждый в своем доме!
Если указать адрес их дома, это может сработать?

Comment: CSS работает только в направлении от родителя к потомку и от sibling к sibling. От потомка к родителю движение невозможно. Используй JS.

Comment: :valid не будет работать на div, он работает только на input

Comment: 1. Я не пытаюсь указать родителю поведение с помощью потомка!
2. Я не цепляю :valid на div, он попрежнему висит на input
Я всего лишь пытался указать полный путь каждому input'у

Answer (score 1):

Вот как-то так:

```
input:valid + input[type="submit"] { ... }
```

Почитайте про [соседние](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/adjacent) и [родственные](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/sibling) селекторы